# Apache 403 Permission Denied

Tags: python, django, apache, http-status-code-403

I am trying to access a website which I am running with Apache. The issue is that that I get a 403 Error and only land on the Permission Denied error page. The backend etc. itself is using Django.

What I get from the error log:

> (13)Permission denied: access to /index/ denied

I also edited the default apache conf to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerM$
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, $
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/acess.log combined

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

WSGIDaemonProcess djangoapps python-path=/home/djangoa$
WSGIProcessGroup djangoapps
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/djangoapps/plugit/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/djangoapps/plugit>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The loaded (I hope) wsgi.py file doesn't include more then the default content yet. I also set `www-data:www-data` on everything in the project..

Comment: This should be asked in http://serverfault.com/ not stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using?? Are you getting root access to your server?? If yes, check if SELinux is disabled or not. If not, then disable it by running **`setenforce 0`** on your server's terminal to disable it.

---

Q. What is SELinux?

A. **Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux)** is a Linux kernel security module (kind of a system firewall) similar to AppArmour.

Comment: Oh, I should have added that. It is a virtual server on which I have running Debian 7 which I am root of. `setenforce` doesn't seem to exist though. Some googling told me that `echo 0>/selinux/enforce` should do the same. Unfortunately no change whatsoever. =(

Comment: Did you reboot the server after making the change?

Comment: If yes, and it's still not working, check if this file exists: `/etc/selinux/config` and if it does, edit it and make sure SeLinux is disabled by looking for this line: `SELINUX=disabled`

Comment: `/etc/selinux` got 2 files: semanage.config and config. semanage.config is mostly text/comments right now, config is empty.

Comment: hmm. if that's the case, then add `SELINUX=disabled` below all that and reboot your server. See if that helps.

Comment: After adding `SELINUX=disabled` to both files and another one in `/selinux/` it is not showing the forbidden error anymore :) I am now getting some  python import and 500 error, but that is another issue. Thanks a lot! Pretty relieving after spending 5hours looking elsewhere..

Comment: @5h1n Glad I could help :) Do mark this as the correct answer if it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: Does  the user actually have permissions at the Django application level?
I know that the admin will give this error when I have created a new model, but the user doesn't have permissions (I often don't notice becuase my superuser allows me to see everything).

Comment: @wobbily_col I'm not very familiar with Django but I think you need to `chown` the Django directory to the user adding the new model and provide proper `chmod` permissions to the main directory, the sub-directory and the files under the main directory.

Comment: @andrew It may well be at the system level rather than the Django level, but that was an obvious thing to check before digging deeper.